# Calling .py script from .sh script error "ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery"

Tags: bash, scripts, python, cron

I have a python script I wish to call each day with a cron job. Because the .py script loads several files from it's directory, rather than change all the file paths within the .py script to be full paths, I instead called a .sh script with the cronjob that changes the dir. Here's the .sh script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/ga_data/gaV4
python gaAPIWorkingVersion.py
echo "ran cron at" | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
echo $(date) | tee -a  "$tvaUpdater.log"
```

I know that the cronjob ran because I see the right date in the log file. However, the log file contains a message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gaAPIWorkingVersion.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from apiclient.discovery import build ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery

The package is installed. When I call the .sh script directly, outwith cron, everything works as expected.

```
/home/ubuntu/ga_data/myscript.sh # works
```

It's only when the script is called from the cron that this error happens.

What could be causing this and is there anything I can add to my crontab or .sh script to successfully run the script?

Note, if it's useful or important, I'm using Anaconda python.

Comment: Yes it is important - `cron` runs in a very limited environment, which almost certainly won't include any `PATH` and/or `PYTHONPATH` that you have set to allow you to run anaconda python from your interactive shell

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the information here. Are you abel to advise how I can correct for this? Is there a line I need to add to my .sh script?

Comment: Find out what relevant variables Anaconda has set (likely added to your `~/.bashrc` file by the Anaconda installation process) and add the same to the top of your bash script

Answer (score 0):

Had to prepend the python path in the crontab per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937976/configure-crontab-job-use-anaconda-python-packages) SO answer.

e.g. `01 00 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/data_scripts/test.py`